# NameError: name 'capital' is not defined

Tags: python

I run this code commission,profit_target all other variable works but only capital giving error. Please anyone can resolve this.

```
def strategy_logic(df,open_position=0,state='Close',capital=0,commission=0,profit_target=0,
                            stoploss=0,quantity=0):

    last_buy=0
    print(open_position,state,capital,commission,profit_target,stoploss,quantity)
    # Run Loop and check Strategy
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df['capital'][i]=capital
        PT=profit_target+last_buy    # PT (Profit Target)
        SL=last_buy-stoploss         # SL (Stoploss)

        # BR (BarRange)
        def BarRange(value):
            if df['High'].iloc[i] >= value >=df['Low'].iloc[i] :
                return True
            return False

        def calculate_open_position():
            global open_position,capital
            print(open_position,commission,stoploss)
            open_position=1
            capital=capital-commission*quantity
            capital=capital-df[state].iloc[i]*quantity
            df['capital'][i]=capital
            df['Buy'][i]=1
            last_buy=df[state].iloc[i]
            print('buy',last_buy)
    
    calculate_open_position()

strategy_logic(df,open_position=0,state='Close',capital=1000,commission=1,profit_target=6,stoploss=3,quantity=1)
```

Comment: There is no *global* `capital` anywhere in your code. Did you mean `nonlocal`?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
global open_position,capital
```

Those variables are not global; they are `nonlocal`. They belong to the namespace of the enclosing function, not the global namespace.

```
nonlocal open_position,capital
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are defining functions inside the for loop and then only calling the last definition after the loop. It would be better to just define them separately and call them with the necessary arguments.

Furthermore, inside `calculate_open_position()` you are assigning last_buy inside the function, where its scope is inside the function. You can verify and see that your variable `last_buy` in the `strategy_logic()` scope is still 0 at the end of the function (assigning it from within the `calculate_open_position` function scope does not change the value in the outer scope).

Also, not sure where you are calling `BarRange()` since it is stuck inside the `strategy_logic()`'s scope and can't be called anywhere else. You might want to read up more about scopes before trying to add `global` from within your function, which is generally a bad practice.

The simplest answer is to remove the definition and run the code directly:

```
def strategy_logic(df, open_position=0, state='Close', capital=0,
                   commission=0, profit_target=0, stoploss=0, quantity=0):

    last_buy = 0
    print(open_position,state,capital,commission,profit_target,stoploss,quantity)

    # Run Loop and check Strategy
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df['capital'][i]=capital
        PT = profit_target + last_buy    # PT (Profit Target)
        SL = last_buy - stoploss         # SL (Stoploss)

        # Run the code here directly instead of defining a function
        open_position = 1
        capital = capital - commission * quantity
        capital = capital - df[state].iloc[i] * quantity
        df['capital'][i] = capital
        df['Buy'][i] = 1
        last_buy = df[state].iloc[i]
        print('buy', last_buy)
```